# Usercake login associated with facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, usercake

My website has a registration  and access system that uses "usercake" system. Now, following the directions on http://www.krizna.com/demo/login-with-facebook-using-php/ , I managed to include a table in the database that stores the fields for each access by working facebook login. The registration details and access with usercake are stored in another tabella.If someone knows the class_user.php files, login.php, funcs.php, config.php, i ask : "is it possible to link data from the two tables so that you have both traditional access with usercake both access and with button "facebook" login?

Answer (score -1):

Why not use UserSpice? Yuu can upgrade usercake 2.0.2 all the way to UserSpice current and use the built in Facebook (and Google) oauth.